# MySQL user privilege to dump stored procedures

Tags: mysql

I am creating a MySQL user to backup stored procedures. This backup user is working except it doesn't export the stored procedures on the dump file.

These are the privileges that I enabled in my backup user.

```
GRANT LOCK TABLES, SELECT
```

Should I add `EXECUTE ON` or what is missing on the privileges?

The root user is working and was able to export stored procedures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to grant `SELECT` privilege on `mysql.proc` table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines